# Unable to send `value` with payable function in Solidity

Tags: solidity, ether, calldata

I am unable to specify a `value` parameter when calling a payable function in Solidity.

The function in question has the following signature: `function batch(bytes[] calldata calls) external payable returns(bytes[] memory results)`

Yet when calling it I get the following compiler error:

```
error[7006]: TypeError: Cannot set option "value" on a non-payable function type.
   --> test/RecipeHarness.t.sol:214:9:
    |
214 |         ladle.batch{ value: user.balance }(batch);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Alternatively, `address(ladle).call{ value: user.balance }(abi.encodeWithSelector(ladle.batch.selector, batch));` is successful.

Is it not possible to specify `msg.value` with any other function besides `call`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your contract clearly think `batch` isn't payable, double check the interface you're using?

Comment: Ah, this was the problem! I assumed the interface was implemented correctly.

Comment: I've only seen `value` provided with `call` before so I assumed the other way wasn't valid syntax. And the Solidity docs didn't have much info on this from what I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created an instance for ladle? "Ladle ladle" ?

address.call is low-level, that's why it works without an instance

Comment: I'm using a mainnet fork in Foundry. So the contract exists exactly as it does here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x6cb18ff2a33e981d1e38a663ca056c0a5265066a

Answer (score 0):

it works for me.

```
contract Ladle {
function batch(bytes[] calldata calls)
    external
    payable
    returns (bytes[] memory results)
{
    uint256 a = 1;
}
```

}

```
contract ladletest {
Ladle ladle;

function a(bytes[] calldata batch) external payable {
    ladle.batch{value: 1}(batch);
}
```

}